# ¿Cómo puedo escribir CSV en Python 3 utilizando Pandas sin que trunque el fichero?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Necesito escribir en un un mismo CSV cada día, pero cada vez que compilo reescribe el archivo desde cero. Mi idea sería leer la cantidad de líneas que tiene escrito el archivo y escribir en esa fila la nueva información.

Actualmente lo estoy realizando de esta forma:

```
creacion = {0: [0.081818182000000003], 2: [0.30769230800000003], 8: [0.0]})
my_df = pd.DataFrame(creacion) 
my_df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False, header=False,sep=';',decimal=',')
```

La salida que obtengo del CSV es:

```
0,081818182;0,307692308;0
```

Pero si compilo nuevamente otra información lo reescribe desde cero:

```
creacion = {3: [0.0], 4: [0.22222], 5: [0.1]})
my_df = pd.DataFrame(creacion) 
my_df.to_csv('out.csv', index=False, header=False,sep=';',decimal=',')
```

La salida que obtengo del CSV es:

```
0;0,22222;0,1
```

La salida aceptable sería:

```
0,081818182;0,307692308;0
0;0,22222;0,1
```

Lo otro, ¿se podría también añadir la clave del diccionario directamente?

Lo que quiero hacer idealmente es esto:

```
0;0,081818182
2;0,307692308
8;0
3;0
4;0,22222;0,1
5;0,1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que estás truncando el archivo cada vez. Por tanto, lo que debes hacer es abrir el fichero previamente en modo "append" (adjuntar) en lugar de "write" (que trunca lo que ya había).

Esto lo puedes hacer utilizando el parámetro `mode` y poniéndole "a" para que sobrescriba el "w" que tiene por defecto:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame(creacion) 
my_df.to_csv('out.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=False,sep=';',decimal=',')
#                       ^^^^^^^^
```

Más información en la página de referencia [`pandas.DataFrame.to_csv()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Comment: Buena respuesta, ahora estoy intentando escribir las claves del diccionario y darle otro orden.

Answer (score 0):

El ejemplo que pones es un poco confuso porque creas dataframes con distintas columnas y al final lo pivotas, pero lo puedes conseguir con:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({0: [0.081818182000000003], 2: [0.30769230800000003], 8: [0.0]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({3: [0.0], 4: [0.22222], 5: [0.1]})
res = df.append(df2).stack()
idx = res.index.droplevel(0)
res.index = idx
```

con salida

```
0    0.08182
2    0.30769
8    0.00000
3    0.00000
4    0.22222
5    0.10000
```

Comment: Los dos diccionarios son creados por información en periodos distintos. En el ejemplo puse ambos, pensando en la forma de seguir escribiendo un mismo archivo CSV sin borrar lo que ya se encontraba escrito. En tu solución generas 2 DateFrame pero solo tengo que tener uno, el cual por cada ejecución del código genere datos distintos que deben ser escritos en el CSV. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

estoy tratando de escribir en un archivo csv basándome en lo que tengo aca 
my_df=pd.DataFrame({'Lanzamiento':[3], 'Puntaje':[Score]})
my_df.to_csv('Puntajes2.csv', mode='a', index=False, header=True,sep=';',decimal=',')

lo que quiero es que el titulo solo se escriba una vez 
ya que me esta saliendo repetidas veces